# Which one is bigger $D(P\Vert Q)$ or $D(Q \Vert P)$?

Tags: statistics, information-theory

In general the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) is asymmetric. If $P$ and $Q$ are two distributions $D(P\Vert Q) \ne D(Q\Vert P)$.  However, I was wondering if there are situations where we can say which one is bigger $D(P \Vert Q)$ or $D(Q \Vert P)$?

In particular if $P(x,y)$ is a joint distribution with marginals $P_X(x)$ and $P_Y(y)$ and we set $Q(x,y) = P_X(x) \times P_Y(y)$ can we compare $D(P \Vert Q)$ and $D(Q \Vert P)$?

Comment: In that case $D(P\Vert Q)$ would be the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$. I don't know what $D(Q\Vert P)$ is. Have you tried computing a few cases numerically?

Comment: @SuzuHirose Indeed you are right. I remember to have heard some name for the other one $D(Q \Vert P)$ like inverse mutual information or so. However, I tried to google that and didn't get any reasonable results. 

It is a good idea to try to compute it for some simple. I haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: Well, I guess we can find some examples where $D(Q\Vert P) = \infty$. Suppose there is a point $(x,y)$ for which $P(x,y) = 0$ but $P_X(x) \ne 0$ and $P_Y(y) \ne 0$. Then $D(Q \Vert P) = \infty$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular case with $P=P_{X,Y}$ being the joint distribution with marginals $P_X$ and $P_Y$, and $Q=P_X\times P_Y$ is addressed in the paper

https://www.princeton.edu/~verdu/lautum.info.pdf

$D(P_X \times P_Y || P_{Y,X})$ is called the lautum information. In the paper, it is found that for the BSC (Theorem 12) and Gaussian channel (Theorem 15), $L(X;Y) \geq I(X;Y)$.